# Flush output continuously with xargs

Tags: bash, xargs, echo, printf

The function output the size of the downloaded file and the speed of transfer separated with newline.
Example:

```
20 #<< data
3.0M #<< speed
25
1.2M
```

Now, it goes like this:

`output_data_func | xargs printf "Data transferred : %s\nSpeed : %s"` and this command works well in placing the data successfully but the issue is that all of the data is output at last at once. I want it to continuously as the function outputs the next values.

I also tried `stdbuf -o0 xargs printf ...` but no success at all.

I tried with echo but I can't place both of them at correct place.

Two probable solutions expected.
Either

- **continuous printing with printf** or
- **correct placement with echo**

Answer (score 1):

While passing `-n2` to `xargs` to call one `printf` for every 2 words on input instead of passing as many arguments as possible (not guaranteed to be an even number) would fix it, that would mean forking one process and loading, initialising, running, cleaning-up one `printf` executable for every two lines.

Best would be to use a text-processing utility to process text.

Even `sed` or `awk` would be enough here:

```
output_data_func | sed 's/^/Data transferred : /; n; s/^/Speed : /'
```

```
output_data_func | awk '
  {getline speed; print "Data transferred : "$0"\nSpeed : "speed}'
```